# Yii2 and storing data in database as UTC

Tags: php, mysql, yii, timezone, yii2

I'm using `Yii2` and I was wondering how it decides what timezone to store the data in the database as?

I have noticed the [$defaultTimezone](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#$defaultTimeZone-detail) which seems to indicate it simply controls what timezone your *input* data is supposed to be when passing it to functions such as the the [asTime](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-formatter.html#time-zones) function and it uses the [formatter timezone](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#$timeZone-detail) to convert said data into the correct time output.

But I'm wondering how do you make sure it is inserting the data into your database in the right timezone so then the value of `$defaultTimezone` can be trusted?

Is there a need to run something like this for `MySQL`:

```
SET time_zone = timezonename;
```

Comment: try this   date_default_timezone_set("you time zone");    in you config ..file

Comment: @SahilManchal That is pretty much what the application timezone does.

Comment: `unix_timestamp` is better when you take care about timezone

Comment: @NgôVănThao I probably *will* be using unix timestamps the most and I know they are UTC by definition, but I guess what confuses me is that you will get a different output integer in PHP depending on what your timezone is set to; so I wanted to make sure it was stored as UTC.

Comment: No. `unix_timestamp` it is not affected by timezone

Comment: I don't mean the mysql function `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` I mean ones you create in PHP using functions such as `time()` or `strtotime()`.

Comment: `unix_timestamp` is the same in any language. But `strtotime()` is an other case. Input string is affected by timezone.

Comment: @NgôVănThao What I'm trying to say is you're going to get different results from `time()` depending on what your setting is in `date_default_timezone_set()`.

Comment: @NgôVănThao So it seems if you have a unix timestamp generated with PHP then you are going to need to convert it into UTC before storing it in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is what I have discovered regarding this:

**timestamp:**

MySQL will automatically store this value as `UTC` and will convert what you give it to UTC and back based on the mysql server time zone.

However, some notes:

I would recommend to set your server timezone to `UTC` with something like this:

```
SET time_zone = 'UTC';
```

Then it won't matter if you have servers all over the world you will always get the same data passed back on each server - this will be the same data as you passed to it, so this will be based on your PHP timezone, so if you want it to *pass back* a `UTC` time then you should use the `NOW()` myswl function to store the TIMESTAMP.

If you don't set the server timezone MySQL will generally rely on the `SYSTEM` timezone and each server would get a different timestamp back based on their timezone.

If you want to implement a `UTC` change into an *existing* system, then it will act differently. No matter what you pass it, it seems it will always return the date as `UTC`.

If you had your server timezone set to `UTC` and then you change it to something else then that's when things start to look a little hairy.

**date** and **datetime**

As far as I'm aware these just store and return the exact data you give them.

**Storing unix timestamps:**

As above these will just store whatever value you give them since you are just storing them as any old `integer`; *but* if you want to store the timestamp in UTC then you can use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` as stated by @Ngô Văn Thao or if you need to do it in PHP then you can do something like this:

```
$tz = new DateTimeZone('UTC'); 
$dt = new DateTime("now", $tz);
$utc_timestamp = $dt->format('U');
```

The `U` represents the unix timestamp formatting option within the php date function; you can use any of the [formatting options](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters) if you want to return the date in another format.

So in short...

- Set your server time to `UTC` using `SET time_zone = 'UTC'`
- Use `NOW()` when inserting data into `TIMESTAMP` fields
- Use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` or the provided code above to store your `unix timestamps` in UTC

Doing the above should always make sure you get the relevant times/dates back in UTC format.

Comment: `$timestamp = time() - date('Z');`. That's just a comment, not a formal document and the most important, it is a mistake. Let's try: ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Berlin');
echo 'Europe/Berlin-->'.time().'<br/>';
ini_set('date.timezone', 'UTC');
echo 'UTC:time-->'.time().'<br/>';

Comment: So you're effectively saying that `$timestamp = time() - date('Z');` won't get the current `UTC` timestamp?

Comment: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` do not care about timezone. Because it always is UTC.
why don't you read the first comment (116 vote up): http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php#100220
Reading more about `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: @NgôVănThao Exactly, timezone independent. Meaning it is going to return *different* values based on the timezone. Value of `time()` in `UTC` != value of ``time()` in another timezone.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use only one timezone for your application you can just add the following line to your config file or the entry script (web/index.php by default):

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Comment: No, I just need to make sure it's being inserted into the database as `UTC`.

Comment: Then use TIMESTAMP, that way you know MySQL will modify the value to UTC, using the server timezone as the timezone for the original value to be inserted.

Comment: Does that mean the server timezone should match the PHP timezone setting?

Comment: nvm... I found my answer; you don't. It seems mysql will return the same value you passed it even if the PHP timezone and mysql timezones are different.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here: https://gist.github.com/SilverFire/6f98d2605a6574bd02f7

It worked for me very well, specially because I work with mysql inside docker container.

In your "config/db.php" add the config below, but remember to replace 'America/Manaus' with your UTC:

```
return [

    // ... your database config goes here, and after:

    'on afterOpen' => function($event) {
        // $event->sender refers to the DB connection
        $event->sender->createCommand("SET time_zone = 'America/Manaus'")->execute();
    }
];
```