# Issue in yii2 timezone formatter

Tags: yii2

in php.ini timezone is UTC. system timezone is UTC. yii defaultTimeZone is UTC. But my datetime attribute gets converted to my timezone "Asia/Kolkata" before saving into db.

Eg: UTC time 12:00Hrs
my input 17.30hrs
what I expect in db is 12:00hrs and in view 17.30hrs
But what I got in db is 17:30hrs and in view I got 23:00hrs.

web.php:

```
'formatter' => 
        [
            'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
            'dateFormat' => 'php:d-m-Y',
            'datetimeFormat' => 'php:d-m-Y H:i a',
            'timeFormat' => 'php:H:i A',
            'timeZone' => 'Asia/Kolkata',
        ],
```

Comment: i have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to save a specific timestamp value using a predefined format. So let's take you have defined your datetime field in the backend as an INTEGER and you want to save it as a integer. You can set the behavior like this

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'timestamp' => [
            'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
            'attributes' => [
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => 'creation_time',
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'update_time',
            ],
            'value' => function() { return date('U'); // unix timestamp },
        ],
    ];
}
```

You can configure [yii\i18n\formatter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html) to control your global date formats for display for your locale. You can set something like this in your config file that you can access across

```
'formatter' => 
        [
            'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
            'dateFormat' => 'php:d-m-Y',
            'datetimeFormat' => 'php:d-m-Y H:i a',
            'timeFormat' => 'php:H:i A',
            'defaultTimeZone' OR 'timeZone' => 'Asia/Calcutta', //global date formats for display for your locale.
        ],
```

Read this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275510/yii2-and-storing-data-in-database-as-utc) and also refer [Doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/684/save-and-display-date-time-fields-in-different-formats-in-yii2/).

Hope its works.