# Datetime format is not same with database in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I want to make datetime format in my view in yii2 project is not same with datetime in my database. I use this code:

```
return Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime($model->tanggal_sampai, "php:d M Y H:i");
```

The datetime in database is : 2016-06-14 16:53:40

But when I see the result of the code above in yii2, the result is not same. The result is : 14 Jun 2016 18:53

There is no problem with the date, but the time is very different. What's the problem? I use format 'WIB' because I'm in Indonesia.

Comment: Are you working in the same timezone? Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33139434/issue-in-yii2-timezone-formatter

Comment: When I store the date into database I use WIB timeZone, but when I show it in yii2 project, I just use the code above.

Comment: Does it get stored correctly? When the datetime gets set is the inserted datetime the same as real time?

Answer (score 1):

In your main config file, put:

```
'components' => [
         'formatter' => [
            'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
            'dateFormat' => 'php:m/d/Y',
            'datetimeFormat' => 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s',
            'timeFormat' => 'php:H:i:s',
         ],
```

And you will get:

```
echo Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime('2016-06-14 16:53:40');
```

> 2016-06-14 18:53:40

It takes the time as **UTC**, and adds +2 because of my Timezone. If you define `date_default_timezone_set` in index as **UTC** or `Yii::$app->timeZone = 'UTC'` it won't transform the time you've saved in your database.

> 2016-06-14 16:53:40

**INFO**: *Timezones for Asia* http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php